# how to fix error laravel 5.2 "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" without composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've got this error in my laravel 5.2 project who hosted in debian linux

```
Warning: require_once(/home/u706561288/public_html/sap/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/u706561288/public_html/sap/vendor/autoload.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/u706561288/public_html/sap/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in 
/home/u706561288/public_html/sap/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
```

so many forum like stackoverflow tell me to using php artisan "composer update" but
unfortunately my hosting package not available to composer instalation
please tell me  how to fix this problem

Answer (score 11):

I suggest that you test these steps

- On the Localhost, run these two commands  (`composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`)
- Re-upload the entire project on the server

Also, if the problem is not resolved, you can delete the ‍`Vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file and run the `composer install` command and Re-upload the entire project again.

Comment: my hosting package not available to composer installation

Comment: I am run my project in cloud hosting service. at the begining my project sucessfully tested in localhost with no error

Answer (score 3):

When the hosting service or some PC does not allow to install Composer and appears error like in my case, follow these steps:

1. Delete all laravel project in hosting service. I recommend to use smartftp for good speed file access and tracked action.
2. Back to our localhost project and run `composer install --no-scripts` command and then `composer clearcache`.
3. Reupload all laravel project.
4. Don't forget to configure `.env` file.

I hope this can help with the same problem in future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while back, what I did to solve it was. I delete all the vendor folder from the root project then install it back by executing `composer install`

Comment: in my case it's happen in production server when I deploy my project.I did not delete my vendor folder, I just copy and paste manually all laravel folder including vendor dependencies. it's litle wasting my time but it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

delete the ‍Vendor folder and the composer.lock file and run the composer install command and Re-upload the entire project again

this helped me

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing the issue after deleting the vendor directory and did `composer install` try to update your composer by `composer selfupdate` then do the same install process.